# Shared worker taking 100% cpu within Chrome when looking at Pull Requests on GitHub

Tags: google-chrome, cpu-load

Recently I have noticed my fans ramping up on my laptop significantly when using google Chrome to look at GitHub. Looking at the chrome task manager this is due to a shared worker process. I do not understand what this process is doing but cannot reasonably understand why it might need 100% of one of my cores (dual core laptop). Has anyone else encountered such an issue for GitHub on Ubuntu or a Ubuntu based distro like Mint?

[image: Task Mnager]